# Nested squared brackets

Tags: python, regex

I have a pattern like this:

```
word word one/two/three word
```

I want to match the groups which is seperated by the `/`. My thought is as follows:

```
[\w]+ # match any words
[\w]+/[\w]+ # followed by / and another word
[\w]+[/[\w]+]+ # repeat the latter
```

But this does not work since it seems as soon as I add `]`, it does not close the mose inner `[` but the most outer `[`.

How can I work with nested squared brackets?

Comment: this is not how sets work in regex (`[]`). you probably want groups (`()`)

Comment: Wait...do you want to match the individual terms in `one/two/three`, or do you want to match the terms themselves?

Comment: I want to match `one/two/three`

Comment: Your incorrect idea of what square brackets mean is a very common FAQ. I suggest people stay away from square brackets entirely at least until they are reasonably familiar with basic regex.

Comment: You have a TARGET STRING like this `word word one/two/three word`. What do you specifically want to extract from that ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using `re.findall`:

```
import re
input = "word word one/two/three's word apple/banana"
r1 = re.findall(r"[A-Za-z0-9'.,:;]+(?:/[A-Za-z0-9'.,:;]+)+", input)
print(r1)

["one/two/three's", 'apple/banana']
```

### Demo

Comment: What if the string is `one/two/three's`, how do I change the regex to cover more than just `\w`?

Comment: @user1406177 The easiest way to do this might be to just add that punctuation to a character class, along with alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following answer using a simple regex very close from yours and from @Tim Biegeleisen's answer, but not exactly the same:

```
import re
words = "word word one/two/three's word other/test"
result = re.findall('[\w\']+/[\w\'/]+', words)
print(result)  # ["one/two/three's", 'other/test']
```